# How to Show $R(L_A L_Q) = L_A L_Q (\mathbb{F}^n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling with where this is coming from in my linear algebra book. We are trying to prove that if $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and $P$ and $Q$ are invertible $m \times m$ and $n \times n$ matrices, respectively, then we have $rank(A) = rank(AQ)$. It is shown that:
$$R(L_{AQ}) = R(L_A L_Q) = L_A L_Q (\mathbb{F}^n) = L_A(\mathbb{F}^n) = R(L_A)$$
I don't understand where $R(L_AL_Q) = L_A L_Q (\mathbb{F}^n)$ is coming from? Is this something absolutely trivial and stupid that I'm overlooking, like $L_A$ is defined to be the mapping from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $\mathbb{F}^m$ and hence the range of $L_A L_Q$ can be all things given by multiplying anything from $\mathbb{F}^n$ so that the "inner dimensions" match?

Comment: $R$ means the range, right? For any function $f:A\to B$ we have $R(f)=f(A)$ by definition. I don't understand your doubt and what is this 'inner dimensions match'.

Comment: Oh, actually, this was such a trivial question. I apologize. If you just write that as an answer below, I'll mark it as the right answer. It should be as simple as that. Piggyback from you, if $L_A: \mathbb{F}^n \mapsto \mathbb{F}^m$, then it should be $R(L_A) = L_A(\mathbb{F}^n)$ by definition.

Comment: I don't exactly wish to close it though, because I did see this question mentioned in another post (but it was never answered and it was extremely old). Hence, I'm sure that someone in the future may also have this very trivial thought as well and would come here just to see it was a quick resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any function $f:A\to B$, its range $R(f)$ is just $f(A)=\{f(a):a\in A\}$ by definition.